# What does `S` signify in SymPy?

Tags: python, sympy

I am new to SymPy, and I can't figure out

```
from sympy.core import S
```

What is `S` actually? And what does `S.true` mean?

Comment: [Singleton](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/modules/core.html#module-sympy.core.singleton).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no research effort.

Comment: @erip I just tried looking for the answer and it actually wasn't obvious to me!  I would not close.  Also, the docs for `Singleton` are ... less than explicit about what it means or when to use it :) .

Comment: In `isympy`, you can use `S?` to get documentation.

Comment: I'm the lead developer of SymPy and I can confirm that it isn't obvious (both existing answers are slightly wrong), and this is a common question. It should not be closed.

Comment: I was surprised by the downvotes, this looks like an interesting question.

Comment: Thanks @asmeurer and Francesco Bonazzi for the positive note. It really gave me boost :)

Comment: If you are using PyCharm you can Ctr+LeftClick the `S` and it will take you to its source-code. (perhaps it's not adequately documented though; haven't checked)

Comment: @erip No research effort has nothing to do with being off-topic. As for the user being able to find it himself, ye i guess that might be true in some cases.

Comment: @Fermiparadox [Disagree](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). SO shouldn't be a first-stop for code questions.

Comment: Clue: `print('The inverse of True is', ~S.true, 'not', ~True)`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There's a bit of confusion because `S` is actually two things.

**The first thing it is is the `SingletonRegistry`.** Several classes in SymPy appear so often that they are *singletonized*, that is, using some metaprogramming they are made so that they can only be instantiated once. For instance, every time you create `Integer(0)`, this will return the same instance, `Zero`. All singleton instances are attributes of the `S` object, so `Integer(0)` can also be accessed as `S.Zero`.

Singletonization offers two advantages: it saves memory, and it allows fast comparison. It saves memory because no matter how many times the singletonized objects appear in expressions in memory, they all point to the same single instance in memory. The fast comparison comes from the fact that you can use `is` to compare exact instances in Python (usually, you need to use `==` to compare things). Hence, you can test `a is S.Zero` to check if `a` is the `Integer(0)` instance.

For the most part, the fact that certain objects are singletonized is an implementation detail that you shouldn't need to worry about. The primary advantage of `S` for end users is the convenient access to certain instances that are otherwise difficult to type, like `S.Half` (instead of `Rational(1, 2)`), or `S.true` (side note: `S.true` is the SymPy version of `True`. Unlike `True`, it does not subclass from `int`, so you can write things like `~S.true` (not true) and it will give `S.false` (contrast that with `~True`, which gives `-2`, which isn't false as a boolean).

**The second thing it is is a shortcut for `sympify`.** `sympify` is the function that converts Python objects such as `int(1)` into SymPy objects such as `Integer(1)`. It also converts the string form of an expression into a SymPy expression like `sympify(x**2) ->  Symbol("x")**2`. `S(1)` is the same thing as `sympify(1)` (basically, `S.__call__` has been defined to call `sympify`).

This is for convenience, since `S` is a single letter. It's mostly useful for defining rational numbers. Consider an expression like `x + 1/2`. If you enter this directly in Python, it will evaluate the `1/2` and give `0.5` (or just `0` in Python 2, because of integer division), because both arguments are `int`s. However, in SymPy, you usually want the quotient of two integers to give an exact rational number. The way Python's evaluation works, at least one side of an operator needs to be a SymPy object for the SymPy evaluation to take over. You could write this as `x + Rational(1, 2)`, but this is a lot more typing. A shorter version is `x + S(1)/2`. Since `S(1)` returns `Integer(1)`, the division will return a `Rational` type, since it will call `Integer.__div__`, which knows how to return a `Rational`.

Comment: So, it means that if I write `if f is S.true` (where `f` is an expression) will just check whether f is true, if yes it further checks the condition.

Comment: Am I interpreting it right @asmeurer
 *Note: This is in reference with the module `sympy.solvers.solveset` line `837` 
[link](https://github.com/Yathartha22/sympy/blob/master/sympy/solvers/solveset.py)

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation!  Would you please also update the [official docs](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.singleton.S) when you have a chance? ;)

Comment: @cxw good idea. I've opened a pull request [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/12105).

Answer (score 2):

As many have linked, [`S`](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/modules/core.html#sympy.core.singleton.S) is for accessing singletons.  Per [the source](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/core/singleton.py#L55), `S` is an instance of `class SingletonRegistry`.  `S` does two things:

- gives you access to instances such as `S.One` and `S.Zero`, which represent fundamental constants
- lets you create or access singletons representing constants based on their values (e.g., `S(1)`).

The reason to use a singleton is so that you can compare objects with `is` rather than `==`.  `is` is faster, but only works if you know *for sure* that your `1` is the same as the `1` you are testing against.  [The code](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/core/singleton.py#L74) gives an example:

```
>>> Basic() is Basic()
False
>>> MySingleton() is MySingleton()
True
 >>> S.MySingleton is MySingleton()
True
```

Comment: Now, If it is
`if f is S.true` where f is an expression(say, `x+1`). What would it mean?

Comment: @Yathartha it is checking that `f` returned exactly the [`True` singleton](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/logic.html#sympy.logic.boolalg.BooleanTrue).  What that means depends on `f`.  I don't know enough sympy to know how `x+1` could return a boolean variable, I'm sorry to say.

Comment: @Yathartha Glad to hear it!  If this answer or Sven's (or both) was helpful, would you please hit the up arrow next to the helpful answer(s)?  If either answer works particularly well for you, would you please hit the checkmark next to that answer?  Those actions will let folks know that you have received help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**In short**

`S.true` is a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) used by SymPy to represent true, and there is a difference with Python `True`:

```
print(f'The inverse of True is {~S.true}, not {~True}')
```

prints:

```
The inverse of True is False, not -2
```

However, such a difference is *usually* hidden to the user, and *in most cases* there isn't any need to use `S.true` directly as SymPy takes care of that for us, using the function `S()` internally, a shorthand for `sympify()`.

This function and the associated singletons are part of `S`, the [singleton registry](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#module-sympy.core.singleton).

Details follow.

---

**`S` is the registry for singletons**

In your context, `S` is the regular shortcut for [singleton registry](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#module-sympy.core.singleton) (`sympy.core.singleton.SingletonRegistry`). This class is itself created by SymPy based on metaclass [Singleton](https://class%20sympy.core.singleton.Singleton).

A singleton relies on object uniqueness instead of value equality, e.g., the singleton `S.Half` is used for rational value `1/2`, whatever the way it has been obtained, e.g., by dividing 2/4 or as the result of `cos(5*pi/3)`. Using this singleton allows equality checks to be based on the singleton ID/address rather than on a value, operator `is` is used. Such comparison is easier and quicker. More on [singleton pattern](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/singleton-pattern-in-python-a-complete-guide/).

For practical purposes, `SingletonRegistry` holds references for constants like `0`, `1`, `False`, `True`, `EmptySet`, etc. in the form of singletons, and can be accessed using its shortcut `S`.

**`S` is also the shortcut for `simpify`**

Note `S`, used as a function, is also the shortcut for function [sympify](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html) which is used by SymPy to make everything used by the program compatible with SymPy, e.g. it identifies strings associated with symbols and give them the correct type. Part of this sympyfication task is to convert constants into their singleton equivalent, when one exists, and `True` is automatically converted into `S.true` when encountered.

**`S.true` is the singleton holding `True`**

Therefore `S.true` (lowercase t) accesses the singleton used by SymPy to represent a `True` value. Normally there isn't any need to use the singleton instead of the Boolean value as in SymPy `True` anyway evaluates to `S.true` when `sympify()` is called. However there are exceptions detailed in the documentation about SymPy [Boolean functions](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/logic.html#boolean-functions):

> SymPy version of `True`, a singleton that can be accessed via `S.true`.
>
> This is the SymPy version of `True`, for use in the logic module. The primary advantage of using `true` instead of `True` is that shorthand Boolean operations like `~` and `>>` will work as expected on this class, whereas with `True` they act bitwise on 1. Functions in the logic module will return this class when they evaluate to true.

**When to use `S.true`?**

From the same page:

> There is liable to be some confusion as to when `True` should be used and when `S.true` should be used in various contexts throughout SymPy. An important thing to remember is that `sympify(True)` returns `S.true`. This means that for the most part, you can just use `True` and it will automatically be converted to `S.true` when necessary, similar to how you can generally use `1` instead of `S.One`.
>
> The rule of thumb is:
>
> “If the boolean in question can be replaced by an arbitrary symbolic Boolean, like `Or(x, y)` or `x > 1`, use `S.true`. Otherwise, use `True`”